# What are the advantages of compiling/interpreting a programming language?

Tags: compilers, interpreters

Interpreted languages give programs dynamic typing and smaller size. Compilied languages tend to be faster and more efficent. What other advantages and disadvantages are there of each?

*(Originally suggested by [Rydwolf Programs](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/users/5/rydwolf-programs) as an example question [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127456/programming-language-design-and-implementation/127457#127457))*

Comment: Please, do not blindly copy/paste the [top questions](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127456/programming-language-design-and-implementation?phase=definition&tab=votes#tab-top) - especially if you mistype the tags. It's better if the author of that question posts it; right now, it even fails to comply to the [referencing requirements](/help/referencing).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it fails to meet referencing requirements

Comment: Hows this off-topic of all the complaints?

Comment: How does this still not meet the referencing requirements

Comment: "*Compiled languages are converted directly into machine code that the processor can then go and execute*" as opposed to interpreted languages where "the processor can then go and execute"? This sentence doesn't provide any significant information. ¶ "*Interpreted languages give programs certain extra flexibility*" but we have no idea what that "certain" something is. ¶ "*What other advantages and disadvantages are there of each?*" — other than what?  The question doesn't actually mention any advantages or disadvantages. ¶ This question isn't bad, it's just *asked* badly.

Comment: Fixed your complaints @RayButterworth

Comment: @Jasmijn failing to meet referencing requirements as defined in [/help/referencing](/help/referencing) is _plagiarism_. If you see plagiarism in a question, you should custom mod-flag it and explain what happened- not close-vote.

Comment: Since someone else who wasn't Rydwolf posted the question, and there's was well-received anyway, I undeleted this question. Why would theirs be treated differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### There is no hard line

There are various techniques that blend the line between compiled and interpreted languages various techniques blur the line, like:

- JIT compilation
- Interpreting bytecode
- Virtual Machines
- Runtime Libraries
- and much more

Still there is a sliding scale of how much work you do at compile time and how much you do at run time.

Some benefits from doing things ahead of time are:

- Code is generally faster to run

  - Interpreted code can get some of these benefits too with JIT or bytecode
- Can run natively without requiring users of a program to download something extra

  - Can be mitigated by building executables that embed the interpreter, eg. py2exe

However, it also comes with downsides:

- Compiling takes time, thus slowing down iteration time during development
- Compiled code needs to be built specifically for every platform it's intended to run on, while interpreted code can run on any platform with a interpreter available

  - Can be mitigated with virtual machines

Overall you can quite easily mix and match what interpreted or compiled features you like best.

Answer (score 1):

**Interpreted Language Advantage**

- Portability: Programs written in interpreted languages can be transferred as source code (or bytecode) to different platforms that have the interpreter implemented, without having to change the program.

Comment: Languages compiled to VM bytecode also have this advantage

Comment: The line gets blurry, but I consider bytecode machines interpreters, which is why my answer also referenced bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

### Compiled Languages Advantages

- Performance: Since compiled languages are translated into machine code, they can generally achieve better performance compared to interpreted languages.
- Security: Since the source code is converted into machine code, it is not directly accessible or readable by users. This can provide an additional layer of security, as the compiled code can be distributed without exposing the original source.

### Interpreted Languages Advantages

- Making changes: When you make a change to a program in a compiled language, you have to go through the compilation process again. For larger projects, this can take several minutes. This does not happen with interpreted languages.